# Filter one table depending on what filter was chosen in other

Tags: excel

I have the following Excel tables:

[image]

I would like to filter the second table depending on the filter of the first table. I mean, if a user filters first table to show only technology then the second table should show only the two technology roles that I have.

Could you give me a hint or a way to go?
Thanks
Regards.

Comment: Maybe you could set the filter of the second table based on the content of cell A2. But that only solves for the case that one service is filtered. What should happen if more than one service in the first table is filtered?

Comment: If more than one service is selected more rows should appear. So if accounting and technology are visitble in left table, in the right one financial roles and technology roles should be visible.Thanks

Comment: I just realized that excel filters the entire rows of the worksheet when applying a filter to a table. Even for a workaround solution it would be necessary to have the two tables on different sheets or use pivot tables instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach, which might work with a little adjustment.

Problematic about filtering tables in excel is that the whole row is turned invisible. Therefore it is necessary to keep the two tables on two seperate sheets or on one sheet below each other.

If the `table1` is on `ws1` the following code filters the `table2` on `ws2` based on the top value filtered in `table1`.

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ws1.Range("A2:A100").Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

Dim str As String
str = rng.Cells(1, 1).Value

With ws2.ListObjects("Table2")
    .Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & str & "*"
End With
```

I know this solution does not answer the question completely, but maybe it helps nevertheless.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I will test it now.